# AWS security rules bug?

Tags: security, iptables, amazon-web-services, port, security-groups

I'm trying to put online a website with HTTPS. I have double checked AWS Security Groups, and everything looks fine.

[image]

I'm running on Node.JS, and this is the app script, so I'm pretty sure it's running on port 443.

```
https.createServer(options, app)
.listen(443)
.on('error', onError)
.on('listening', onListening);
```

**iptables**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:22
```

**ss -tlnp**

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                                   Local Address:Port                                                                  Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                                                                  *:22                                                                               *:*
LISTEN     0      128                                                                 :::22                                                                              :::*
LISTEN     0      128                                                                 :::443                                                                             :::*
```

And the problem is I cannot access the website, and checking in `telnet` got connection refused, in https://networkappers.com/tools/open-port-checker is said: 174.129.96.89 port-443 blocked

Am I missing something here? I have already open a ticket, but no answer til now.

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is.

Comment: You're right, I will edit.

Comment: I can't tell if you truncated the `ss -tlnp` output, but it may be listening only on IPv6. Can you compare `ss -ntlp4` and `ss -ntlp6` and report if :443 is listening on both?

Comment: In fact, only in IPv6 it is appearing. However, listening on port 4000 and opening it, it worked. Any difference to 443?

Comment: What does your network configuration look like on the server? Is this server in a public subnet? Have you double checked there are no conflicting security rules at the subnet or VPC level applied? Have you confirmed there is a public IP assigned to the instance and you are using the correct IP?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you disable iptables?

Comment: What about explicitly listening on IPv4? Possibly, you need to `.listen(443,'0.0.0.0')`.

Comment: Run  netstat -lt   To confirm that the your node app is actually listening on the ports you expect

Comment: Does your VPC have an internet gateway? Does your subnets have route tables?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your iptables rules aren't set up right. Here's a reference on the [correct rules for HTTP and HTTPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands). Cutting the relevant rules from the reference:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Sad, but did not worked either.

Comment: hmm, what OS are you using? Ubuntu/CentOS or something else? Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04) will help